# Fetching data from GraphQL server via react(ApolloClient.query()) method

Tags: javascript, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

First of all sorry for my english.
So I am trying to fetch some data from GraphQL server and have several problems,
that's my code:

```
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import 'babel-polyfill';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'https://api.spacex.land/graphql/',
  headers: {
      authorization: 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
  },
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true,
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  }
});

async function fetchedData(params) {
  const fetched = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        launchesPast(limit: 10) {
          mission_name
          launch_date_local
          launch_site {
            site_name_long
          }
          links {
            article_link
            video_link
          }
          rocket {
            rocket_name
            first_stage {
              cores {
                flight
                core {
                  reuse_count
                  status
                }
              }
            }
            second_stage {
              payloads {
                payload_type
                payload_mass_kg
                payload_mass_lbs
              }
            }
          }
          ships {
            name
            home_port
            image
          }
        }
      }
      `,
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    variables: null
  });
  return fetched;
}
```

export default fetchedData().then((res) => console.log(res));

[Browser tab Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qylxv.png)
[Browser tab Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt6UZ.png)

Browser tab Response:

> {"errors":[{"message":"query exceeds complexity
> limit","locations":[{"line":1,"column":1}],"extensions":{"code":"GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED"}}]}

Browser tab console:

> POST https://api.spacex.land/graphql/ 400 (Bad Request);

**And for example the same query via GraphQLClient.request() is working.**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

import { GraphQLClient, gql } from 'graphql-request'

async function fetchedData() {
  const endpoint = 'https://api.spacex.land/graphql/'

  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
    headers: {
      authorization: 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
    },
  })

  const query = gql`query {
    launchesPast(limit: 10) {
      mission_name
      launch_date_local
      launch_site {
        site_name_long
      }
      links {
        article_link
        video_link
      }
      rocket {
        rocket_name
        first_stage {
          cores {
            flight
            core {
              reuse_count
              status
            }
          }
        }
        second_stage {
          payloads {
            payload_type
            payload_mass_kg
            payload_mass_lbs
          }
        }
      }
      ships {
        name
        home_port
        image
      }
    }
  }
  `

  const data = await graphQLClient.request(query)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
  return data;
}
export default fetchedData().catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

[Browser tab Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUdxN.png)
[Browser tab Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC9NT.png)

And Browser tab response is correct

Answer (score 0):

You try make it with `variables` param. Like this?

```js
const query = gql`query($limit: Int) {
    launchesPast(limit: $limit) {
      mission_name
      launch_date_local
      launch_site {
        site_name_long
      }
      links {
        article_link
        video_link
      }
      rocket {
        rocket_name
        first_stage {
          cores {
            flight
            core {
              reuse_count
              status
            }
          }
        }
        second_stage {
          payloads {
            payload_type
            payload_mass_kg
            payload_mass_lbs
          }
        }
      }
      ships {
        name
        home_port
        image
      }
    }
  }
  `
  const variables = { limit: 10 };
  
  const data = await graphQLClient.request(query, variables)
```

In your case

```js
import {
    createHttpLink
} from 'apollo-link-http';
import {
    gql
} from '@apollo/client';
import {
    ApolloClient,
    InMemoryCache
} from '@apollo/client';
import 'babel-polyfill';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'https://api.spacex.land/graphql/',
    headers: {
        authorization: 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
    },
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    connectToDevTools: true,
    query: {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        errorPolicy: 'all',
    }
});

async function fetchedData(params) {
    const fetched = await client.query({
        query: gql`
        query($limit: Int) {
            launchesPast(limit: $limit) {
                mission_name
                launch_date_local
                launch_site {
                site_name_long
                }
                links {
                article_link
                video_link
                }
                rocket {
                rocket_name
                first_stage {
                    cores {
                    flight
                    core {
                        reuse_count
                        status
                    }
                    }
                }
                second_stage {
                    payloads {
                    payload_type
                    payload_mass_kg
                    payload_mass_lbs
                    }
                }
                }
                ships {
                name
                home_port
                image
                }
            }
        }
    `,
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        variables: {
            limit: 10,
        }
    });

    return fetched;
}
export default fetchedData().then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: I went back, opened the Apollo Client DevTools and started deleting each field step by step, eventually I found that the problem was in "rocket {first_stage}" or "rocket {second_stage}". The request can only work if one of them is enabled, but not both at the same time. I don't know how it works, but this is the solution. And especially I can't figure out what is the difference between GraphQLClient().Request() and ApolloClient().Query().